# Passing textbox value to ASP.NET class

Tags: asp.net

I always got this error:Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'txtUserName' does not exist in the current context

mypage.aspx

```
<% @Page Language="C#" Inherits="myclass" Src="myclass.cs" %> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Username:
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Writedata" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## myclass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public class myclass:Page 
{
    protected void WriteData(object sender, EventArgs e){

    string customer_id=txtUserName.Text;



    string postData="customer_id="+customer_id;

    byte[] data= Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);

    // Prepare web request...
    HttpWebRequest myRequest =
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myserverurl.com/mypage.php");
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
    Stream newStream=myRequest.GetRequestStream();
    // Send the data.
    newStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
    newStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Any help here?

Thanks,

Comment: Is this a webapplication or website project? However, the page directive does not contain a `codebehind`. `<%@ Page Language="cs" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="myclass.aspx.cs" Inherits="Namespace.myclass" title="myclass-title" %>`

Comment: it is a website project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your class declaration to "public partial class myclass:System.Web.UI.Page". The partial keyword is, I believe, critical for the compiler to know the balance of the class definition is created in temp/intermediate files it won't know about otherwise.

Comment: Add the "codefile="myclass.cs" to the Page directive in your aspx file.